# Simple Modal isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, simplemodal

I'm trying to create a modal with an iframe but the code isn't working. Nothing happens.

I've already put an `alert` message to see if the function is being called and it is, but the modal isn't created.

Here's my JavaScript code:

```
function iframe(src){
    alert("Message");
    $.modal('<iframe src="' + src + '" height="450" width="830" style="border:0">', {
        closeHTML: "",
        containerCss: {
            backgroundColor: "#fff", 
            borderColor: "#fff", 
            height: 450, 
            padding: 0, 
            width: 830
        },
        overlayClose:true
    });
}
```

I've tried to include a file named `jquery.simplemodal-1.4.3.js` and `jquery.simplemodal-1.4.3.min.js` but it's still not working.

Comment: You only need to include one of those files. Preferably the `min` version if you're on a production system.

Comment: What's the value stored in your `src` variable? Have you tried this on IE, Firefox, Chrome, and Safari? Seems like if you copy example code from the simplemodal home page it ought to work on at least one of those unless there's something wrong with the iframe itself.

Comment: I already solve my problem, the file I include wasn't correct. Ty anyway :)